# Can't play MP3s on external HDD

Tags: windows-media-player

I'm on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

I ripped a CD as MP3s onto my C drive, into My Music. I imported them into my Windows Media Player library. They played fine.

As my C drive is an SSD, I then moved them onto a 4TB external drive, to `E:\# Music\`, and deleted the WMP library items, and added `E:\# Music` to my WMP Library.

When I double-click on an individual MP3 in Windows Explorer in `E:\# Music\`, I receive the error:

> Windows Media Player cannot find the file. If you are trying to play,
>   burn, or sync an item that is in your library, the item might point to
>   a file that has been moved, renamed, or deleted.

What gives? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [How to fix “Windows media player cannot find the file” error](http://www.besttechtips.org/how-to-fix-windows-media-player-cannot-find-the-file-error/) :

[image]

- Firstly you should close Windows Media Player.
- After that you should stop media sharing service. For that you should click on Start, then select Control Panel, Large Icons, Administrative Tools, Services.
  Right-click on the “Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service” and choose Stop.
- Open the following directory: **“C:\Users\”your username”\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player“**. Find and delete there files with the names **CurrentDatabase_*.wmdb*** and **LocalMLS_.wmdb**.
- Then you can start the Media Sharing Service
- Then you can restart Windows Media Player.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks duDE! Any idea why the db becomes corrupt?

Comment: You are welcome, Steve! Sorry, no idea, another one windows' bug ;)